# How do make a tag cloud link to a specific paragraph or picture in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, tags, cloud, href

I've just started using the tag cloud feature for a new site i'm developing. 
but now I've run into some problems
I can set the links in my tag cloud to go to a page, but I have many pages with a tab container.

so for instance, I have a tab container. one of its panels is a sports panel. the tab container has three other panels, say food, travel and drinks.
how do I make a tag that goes directly to that panel in the tab container?
really stuck here.
tried creating a normal a id="something" name="something", and tried creating the tags a href to that name with a #, but that didn't work.

could somebody please help me
would, of course, be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens when you click a tab on the "tabs page"? Is some javascript triggered to show/hide sections? Can you append to that javascript? That's the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A # is your best bet. So for example if you set up your link to appear as:

```
<a href="/yourpagewithtabs.aspx#tagname">Link text</a>
```

Then you can bind to the "hash change" event using javascript. jQuery example below.

```
// on load
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // bind window hashchange event
    jQuery(window).bind("hashchange", function(){

        // get hash selected
        var hash = window.location.hash;

        // *** now do something with that information *** //
        // *** eg, show hide panels where a nested element, attribute or data matches hash *** //

    });
});
```

If you're doing it this way you should make all the "tab clicks" simply bound hash changes too, forgetting any previous functionality. Then it will be solid, and consistent.

You could also do the same using query strings. And if you're not a fan of the "hashchange" then do it another way. The key is that you would have a javascript function that looks for something in the url, then does *something* about it!

**EDIT**

Add to the "do something section" assuming all your tabs are of the same class and the hash is the same name as the ID

```
jQuery(".tabs").hide();
jQuery("#" + hash).show();
```

Comment: so after the var hash = window.location.hash; string, how can I say "link to that panel on that page"?

Comment: sorry for asking so much, new to this sort of thing

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You're already on the panel page. As in, the jquery bit is **for** the panel page...

Comment: sorry. saying I have the link set up as ../default.aspx#findthird  then copied your code for the jscript. now what?

Comment: Put the script in the tabbed page, then where it says "do something", show the relevant panel based on the hash ("findthird").

Comment: ok. almost there. moved the script to the default page (was using a master), and it goes to the page. so now I must say "show this tab panel"? sorry to ask, but could you pls give an example? very much a noob when it comes to jquery. I mostly use code the sites give me. thx very much for the massive help so far

Comment: Ok dude, I'll put an edit in but that's it - this site is for solving problems, not stealing code. Sorry if that sounds harsh, but my rep could go down if I just "give you the code".

Comment: placed an a tag inside the third panel, named it accordingly, but obvs, when the page loads, it goes to the first panel